# awk how to parse based on pattern but skip multiple similar lines and accept only single line occurence

Tags: awk

I got this entry text

```
This connection from x.x.x.x
auth msg from AAA
auth msg from BBB
This connection from x.x.x.x
auth msg from BBB
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from y.z.x.y
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from x.x.x.x
auth msg from AAA
auth msg from BBB
auth msg from CCC
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from y.y.y.x
auth msg from CCC
This connection from x.x.x.a
auth msg from ZZZ
```

and I want the result

```
x.x.x.x BBB
y.y.y.x CCC
x.x.x.a ZZZ
```

I tried as this

```
awk '
  /connection from/ {
    split($6,ip,":"); 
    getline text;
    split(text,player," ")
    if (player[6] == "msg" ) {
        id = player[8]
        print  ip[1],  id
    }    
  }'
```

but this will not work as expected. any hints?If the pattern matches there has to be only 1 msg entry to get output.

Comment: Can you explain the logic on how you get from the sample data to your desired results. It's not clear and backwards engineering your non-working code isn't helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
   /connection from/{ nr=NR; conn[nr]=$NF; auth_counter[nr]=0; next; }
   { auth_counter[nr]++; auth_msg[nr]=$NF; }
   END{
      for(i in auth_counter) if(auth_counter[i]==1) print conn[i], auth_msg[i]  
   }' file

x.x.x.x BBB
y.y.y.x CCC
x.x.x.a ZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- if an ip/single-auth pair shows up more than once in the file, print each occurrence

Sample input:

```
$ cat ip_auth
This connection from x.x.x.x
auth msg from AAA
auth msg from BBB
This connection from x.x.x.x        # print x.x.x.x / 1st time
auth msg from BBB                   # print
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from y.z.x.y
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from x.x.x.x
auth msg from AAA
auth msg from BBB
auth msg from CCC
This connection from x.x.x.x
This connection from y.y.y.x        # print
auth msg from CCC                   # print
This connection from x.x.x.a        # print
auth msg from ZZZ                   # print
This connection from x.x.x.x        # print x.x.x.x / 2nd time
auth msg from PPP                   # print
```

**NOTE:** comments added here for clarification

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_pair() { if (ip && auth) print ip,auth }
/connection from/     { print_pair(); ip=$4; auth=""  }  # print prev pair; start new pair   
/auth/                { if (auth) ip=""; else auth=$4 }  # if auth already set then clear ip, else set auth
END                   { print_pair() }                   # print last pair
' ip_auth
```

This generates:

```
x.x.x.x BBB
y.y.y.x CCC
x.x.x.a ZZZ
x.x.x.x PPP
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's rephrase your apparent requirement: if there is more than one `auth` message after `connection from`, don't print it.

To further rephrase, on the next line after a sequence of these two, if the current line is not another `auth`, print the data you collected from the previous two.

```
awk '/connection from / { conn=$4; tgt=FNR+1; next }
/auth/ && FNR==tgt { auth=$4; atgt=FNR+1; next }
!/auth/ && FNR==atgt { print conn, auth }' filename
```

The built-in variable `FNR` contains the current line number; we use it to anchor the following condition to the next line.